# any replacement for struct.pack?

Tags: python, cpu-registers

I am trying to write a python program to read and write registers from/into Hardware. My read writes fine, but my write does not work. I think the problem is when I do a struct.pack. Can any of you tell me why. Also it will be great if you can share if there is a better way to write into registers via device descriptors. I have already tried (ctypes) and I prefer to have a native python code for doing read/write. thanks for your time..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
from struct import *
from fcntl import *


SIOCDEVPRIVATE = 35312
NF10_IOCTL_CMD_READ_STAT = SIOCDEVPRIVATE + 0
NF10_IOCTL_CMD_WRITE_REG = SIOCDEVPRIVATE + 1
NF10_IOCTL_CMD_READ_REG = SIOCDEVPRIVATE + 2

addr= '0x7d400000'
value= '0x1234'
# Function for writing

f = open("/dev/nf10", "w")
arg = (int(addr, 16) << 32) + int(value, 16)
arg = pack("q",arg)
ioctl(f, NF10_IOCTL_CMD_WRITE_REG, arg)
f.close()

# Function for reading
f = open("/dev/nf10", "r+")
arg = pack("q",int(addr, 16))
value = ioctl(f, NF10_IOCTL_CMD_READ_REG, arg)
value = unpack("q", value)
value = value[0]
value = hex(value & int("0xffffffff", 16))
print value
f.close()
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your own question from earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17426932/1980029? If so it would be better to edit the existing question with more information than open a new one.

Comment: This is not the same one. Here I don't call the functions instead want to know if there is an alternative for struct.pack and if not what are the other alternatives.

Comment: addr= '0x7d400000' .. int(addr, 16) -- you can simply write 0x7d400000 as an integer constant in python - no need to make a string and parse it

Comment: What is `arg`?  What is it supposed to be?

Comment: You might want to give Cython a try; or http://cffi.readthedocs.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a bit dangerous to use struct.pack('q'), since the actual struct (netfpga_register_t) has two 32-bit fields, so a pack('II') would be more appropriate.

Also, in netfpga_register_t, fields come in this order: reg_id and reg_val. If the platform is little-endian, your value is going into the first 4 bytes, not into the last ones. Another good reason to use struct.pack('II', addr, value).